# My CTC loss model's loss stagnates and then outputs only blank characters

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, speech-recognition, mozilla-deepspeech

I am trying to implement BaiDu's DeepSpeech1 in keras using CTC loss, my code is below:

```
class dataGen(Sequence): # data generator for Mozilla common voice
    def __init__(self, audiopaths, transcripts, batch_size):
        self.x = audiopaths
        self.y = transcripts
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return int(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx*self.batch_size : (idx+1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx*self.batch_size : (idx+1)*self.batch_size]

        x_val = [get_max_time(file_name) for file_name in batch_x]
        max_val = max(x_val)

        x_data = np.array([make_mfcc_shape(file_name, padlen=max_val) for file_name in batch_x]) # just converts data to mdcc

        y_val = [get_maxseq_len(l) for l in batch_y]
        max_y = max(y_val)

        labels = np.array([get_intseq(l, max_intseq_length=max_y) for l in batch_y])

        input_length = np.array(x_val)

        label_length = np.array(y_val)

        return [x_data, labels, input_length, label_length], np.zeros((self.batch_size,)), [None] 

  def on_epoch_end(self):
      i = np.arange(len(self.x))
      np.random.shuffle(i)
      self.x = self.x[i]
      self.y = self.y[I]


def clipped_relu(x):
    return relu(x, max_value=20)

def ctc_lambda_func(args):
    y_pred, labels, input_length, label_length = args
    return ctc_batch_cost(labels, y_pred, input_length, label_length)

def ctc(y_true, y_pred):
    return y_pred

input_data = Input(name='the_input', shape=(None, 26))

inner = TimeDistributed(Dense(2048))(input_data)
inner = TimeDistributed(Activation(clipped_relu))(inner)
inner = TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.1))(inner)
inner = TimeDistributed(Dense(2048))(inner)
inner = TimeDistributed(Activation(clipped_relu))(inner)
inner = TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.1))(inner)
inner = TimeDistributed(Dense(2048))(inner)
inner = TimeDistributed(Activation(clipped_relu))(inner)
inner = TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.1))(inner)

inner = Bidirectional(LSTM(2048, return_sequences=True))(inner)
inner = TimeDistributed(Activation(clipped_relu))(inner)
inner = TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.1))(inner)

output = TimeDistributed(Dense(28, activation="softmax"))(inner)

labels = Input(name='the_labels', shape=[None,])
input_length = Input(name='input_length', shape=[1])
label_length = Input(name='label_length', shape=[1])

loss_out = Lambda(ctc_lambda_func, output_shape=(1,), name='ctc'). ([output, labels,     input_length, label_length])

model = Model(inputs=[input_data, labels, input_length, label_length],     outputs=loss_out)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=ctc)
```

This is all pretty standard, however during training, my model reaches a loss usually between 100 and 200 (from >1000) and then stops improving and when I test it (remove lambda layer to get transcript outputs), it only outputs blank characters.

My theory is that it trains to output only blank characters as this gives a lower loss than random characters but then gets stuck at a local minima there and doesn't actually learn to transcribe the audio.

Is there any trick to fix this that someone knows?

Comment: There are so many existing implementations for this, why don't you take the working one. Like https://github.com/robmsmt/KerasDeepSpeech. Also, DeepSpeech is pretty old, there are better models.

Comment: I actually used most of his code in my implementation, which is why I am so confused because it doesn't work

Comment: Does the original implementation work?

Comment: I do not know because it requires dated versions of python and tensorflow. You mentioned better models, could you maybe name a few

Comment: espnet for example